# What is the purpose of the IStorageProviderUriSource / ContentUriSource interface?

Tags: winapi, virtualfilesystem, virtual-drive, cloud-files-api

Windows Cloud Files API provides [IStorageProviderUriSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.provider.istorageproviderurisource) interface (desktop4:ContentUriSource element in manifest). It is implemented in both CloudMirror sample from Microsoft and in Virtual Drive sample from IT Hit.

After running the sample code, I have found that IStorageProviderUriSource methods are called when MS Office application is activated, for example when MS Word is brought to the foreground.

However, the purpose of this interface is still unclear to me. How content ID, that is mentioned in the ContentUriSource documentation can be used?

Comment: I'm guessing this interface is responsible for translating between (local) file paths and (public) URIs. An implementation of this interface has full agency over the desired mapping. The URI can subsequently be used to share cloud storage resources.